# How do I disable|reset the fingerprint scanner on the nexus 6p?

Tags: twrp, nexus-6p, fingerprint

It doesn't work properly since I restored my twrp backup from my old 6p (this one is a replacement). I'd like to remove the fingerprints so I can reset the whole thing, how can I do that?

When I turn on my screen, I also get a litte message which says:

```
Fingerprint hardware not available
```

P.S. I'm rooted in case that helps.

edit: To clarify, I can get past the lockscreen, but deleting the fingerprints in the settings doesn't do anything, they're not being deleted.

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Are you stuck at the lock screen? When you set up finger prints you also have to set up a back-up password in case that doesn't work. Do you not know the back up password/pin? If you're able to get past the lock screen, you can find 'Nexus Imprint' under the Security section in your settings.

Comment: @MR04 sorry should have been clearer, I've edited my post above.

Comment: Android version would also be helpful. I'm running Android 6.0.1 on my Nexus 6P and you cannot delete finger print feature. You can however delete the fingers under Nexus Imprints in the Security section of the settings. You should automatically have a secondary lock regardless whether or not you have fingers saved. This is under screen lock in the settings.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this problem by deleting `/data/fpc/` and the `fpdata` folders in the folders in `/data/system/users/`.

Comment: Thanks! After removing those folders, I rebooted, then I was able to delete the existing fingerprints and readd them. (before I removed these files,  trying to delete the fingerprints cause the phone to crash and reboot)

This problem was caused, for me, by restoring a twrp backup form another phone as mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed by reflashing the stock firmware. It was caused by restoring a twrp backup from another phone (same model).